# 'Global' variables Razor

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm creating a form so members of a site can change the passwords for their accounts, and I'd like to display a message explaining mistakes the users made while filling the fields (such as password too short, needs at least a non-alphanumeric character, etc.). I'd like to display these messages in the same page, beside the field names. Here's my code:

```
@helper RenderForm()
{
  <form method="post">
    <p>Change your password below</p>

    <div><label for="currentPassword">Current Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="currentPassword" name="currentPassword"/></div>

    <div><label for="newPassword">New Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword"/></div>

    <div><label for="confirmPassword">Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"/></div>

    <div><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></div>
  </form>
}

@helper Message(string message)
{
  <p>@message</p>
}

<style type="text/css">
 p,label {color:black;}
</style>


@{
    if(!IsPost) {

         @RenderForm();

    }

    else {
        var account = Membership.GetUser();

        var currentPassword = HttpContext.Current.Request["currentPassword"];

        if(Membership.ValidateUser(account.UserName, currentPassword)){
            var newPassword = HttpContext.Current.Request["newPassword"];
            var confirmPassword = HttpContext.Current.Request["currentPassword"];

            if(check(newPassword, confirmPassword)){
                account.ChangePassword(account.ResetPassword(), newPassword);
            }

        }
        else {
            @Message("The password provided didn't match with the database.");
        }   
    }
}

@functions{

    List<string> check(string newPassword, string confirmPassword)
    {
        //just a place holder
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a List to be filled when an error was found, and when the form was reloaded the message would be displayed, but the RenderForm() function can't find any reference to the List. How can I display these messages?

Comment: You should move all of that code to an action method in a controller and use validation via model binding.

Comment: Since you are using ASP.NET MVC, why not use jquery validation? Also, don't mix controller code in your views. The whole point of MVC is to separate these things.

Comment: seperate that code from the UI, View should have not have all that code in it, that's what a controller is for.

Comment: Is this supposed to be MVC? The title says so, but the code doesn't look to fit the pattern and there's no tag.

Comment: There you go, changed the title. I found out this stuff exists last week, so most of the concepts are still a little muddled for me...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in validation that comes with the Web Pages framework. I have an article that explains how to use it: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/191/Validation-In-Razor-Web-Pages-2

Comment: Can't you upgrade to 2? If not, you should use the ModelState dictionary for logging validation errors rather than building your own container.